# Can I have rows ordered by key and partitioned randomly?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

For example if I process a lot of transactions [timestamp (key), value, trader,..] I would like to have random partitioning for the sake of load balancing.

But for the sake of queries I would like these transactions to be ordered by timestamps on each node so that it would be very fast to go through all transactions in the last 5 minutes (or some other period) and combine totals using MapReduce.

Why does cassandra sort keys in the file randomly if I use random partitioner?

**Q1:** Is there a workaround for this? I could use indexing but it is not ideal.

**Q2.** Out of curiosity I would like to know why is key sorting in one node related to partition strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes is Cassandra are in ring form, each node in ring is responsible for key range (data set). The idea is, to divide data equally over all nodes in ring, and additionally to execute each write operation independently - so that we do not need to keep track of last updates in order to balance data in ring.

Random Partitioner uses [Consistent Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) in order to store row keys on random nodes and in order to find them later on. It basically generates hash of the real row key (this is BigInteger), and it finds node in ring which is responsible for this hash (its within range of this node).

For example, we have 4 nodes in ring (I will use small number in order to keep it simple):

- node 1 = initial_token: 0
- node 2 = initial_token: 100
- node 3 = initial_token: 200
- node 4 = initial_token: 300

Hash of row key "value1" gives 23, so it will be stored on node 1

Hash of row key "value2" gives 123, so it will be stored on node 2

In order to solve your problem you will need to write manual index, and secondary index might be not perfect idea - it has some limitations (low carnality)

Comment: I was using hash partitioning for load balancing but in your example if I want to insert row key "value3" with hash 119 it would be inserted on node 2 before "value2" and I want it to be on node 2 after "value2". Why keys can't be ordered on a single node? What is the reason not to hove sort strategy and partitioning strategy independent of each other? Can you elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: I have a dodgy workaround but it is really bad and it is not easy to add additional nodes. What I did is this: for 5 nodes my key would be MD5(timestamp) mod 5 : timestamp. First byte is used for partitining so I have load balancing and data ordered on each node. Unfortunately is very difficult to add additional nodes.

Comment: well... Cassandra has chosen simple and efficient solution - this is all I do not think that there something more behind this idea. You can have ordered keys within single node by creating wide row - in this case column names are sorted. Your solution with timestamp will not scale - as you already seen. I would redesign your model - create reverse index and use denormalization - this is really not very hard ;)

Comment: Check this out: http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html , or maybe consider using MongoDB

Comment: Thanks Maciej, I redesigned my model and indeed introduced some denormalization and now it works perfectly, have load balancing and sorted transactions on each node! If you are interested I can share my solution tomorrow.

Comment: sure - lots of people has similar problems, this could really help them

Comment: I was away for awhile. There are several solutions to my problem but none was ideal. The one I used was this: I would use random partitioner so that I have load balancing but I would also create a column called transaction_5minute where I would put the values of transation time rounded by 5 minutes. I would put a secondary index on that column. Loading values in that index would be balanced as well because every node would index only values on that node and Hadoop can use index_slice to find the transaction that we need.

Comment: Do you know is there a possibility for a secondary index to contain another attributes beside key values? For example transaction key and transaction amount. In that way I could calculate everything I need by just using this index. I see why it is difficult to maintain in cassandra but for insert-only, non-updatable tables cassandra could support these kind of indices.

Comment: The solution is to use keys of CompositeType in my ColumnFamily so that keys could contain everything I need(time, from, to, value). In that way we don't need to make 2 db reads to get values.